# Where to clear unused fields: in model or in form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Where should I clear unused data fields (for example set `organization_name` to empty string if the `Contract` model is not related to an organization but is a personal contract)?

Should I do it in model or in form/modelform?

I want to clear unused data fields, among other to ease comparison of equality of two model instances (so that erased field would be always compare equal).

Which method(s) should I override to do clearing unused data in it? Should I override `Model.save()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on your expected behavior and it is for you to choose.

For example, if you want to leave ability to create instance that will have `organization_name` set to non-empty string despite of being personal contract manually from console or some other interface, putting that logic into `Model.save()` method will prevent that.

But if you want to avoid that, `Model.save()` is best place for it. But don't depend on that 100%, there is always possibility that it will make it's way to database, unless you will check it on database level.